# Why would I not want to delete a panel when I remove it from a category?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, ribbon

I was looking at the function [CMFCRibbonCategory::RemovePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487023.aspx) and I saw something that I don't understand.  The 2nd optional parameter is `bDelete` which according to the docs:

> [in] bDelete
>
> - TRUE to delete the panel object from memory; FALSE to remove the panel object without deleting it.

I don't see a way of referencing the same panel elsewhere and this isn't like hiding the panel as there is no way to bring it back, so why wouldn't I want to do this?

Unless this is in case I were to keep a live pointer to it using [CMFCRibbonCategory::GetPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb983477(v=vs.120).aspx)?  Sounds kinda like a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree. There is no real use for Setting bDelete to false at all.

m_arPanes is no where accessed in a way that some one can add a Panel with a plain pointer.

It seams to be a relict when they transported the BGC ribbons implementation into the MFC. The BCG version also have this bDelete flag and it isn't useful  there too, but there are more complex functions that handle such panels.
 But I don't see this functions and internal customizable panels in categories in the MFC.

So from the design point it would have been better to create a special protected function like InternalRemovePanel. That just remove th Panel and keps the pointer...

Comment: I'll wait a day or so to see if there is any more answers, but if there are none that diverge from this, I'll mark this as the answer.